# One-to-Many relationship on Core Data

Tags: ios4, core-data, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am having trouble with Core Data, on a one to many relationship.

I have two entities, say Class and Pupils.
A class can have many pupils, but a pupil belongs to only one class.

I can list the Class items and put them in a UITableView object.
I can also list the Pupils items and put them in a UITableView object.

My problem is : for a given class say classX, how can I get the corresponding pupils.

This is the first time I use "relationship" with Core Data.
I tried to find some sample code on the net but with no success.

Thanks for any useful tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your relationship is named "pupils" and you have a managed object for the class called "myClass", then:

```
NSSet *pupilsForClass = [myClass valueForKey:@"pupils"];
for (NSManagedObject *pupil in pupilsForClass) {
    // Do something for each pupil
}
```

If you have NSManagedObject subclasses for Pupil and Class entities, then you can also access properties more directly using setter/getter methods that are generated dynamically by core data.